# Can I generate an SSL certificate on LAMP stack Wordpress and then Move it to Bitnami?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have generated a private key on my Wordpress, I also have SSL certificates from CA and .csr file.

However, I'm in the proccess of moving my Wordpress install to another host (from Google to AWS) and I will be using Bitnami. (I'm using a simple LAMP stack on Google, without Bitnami).

Given that I generated all keys on Google, will my certificate work on AWS if I transfer all keys?

Comment: There is no such thing as 'an SSL'. You are talking about *certificates.*

Comment: Yes, I mean will these certificates allow me to enable https on another host with a different setup? I will be using bitnami as opposed to default lamp stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your host server is identified (for TLS purposes) by the private key you generated.

Provided the new host is configured correctly, your SSL certs will continue to work.

Comment: @alecdwn Thanks, I will be deploying a prebuilt bitnami on aws. So I'm guessing a move from google to amazon will not make a difference

Answer (score 0):

When you change the server you should generate a new CSR and certificate for new server, because it identify the specific server. or you should setup the server according to private key.